# Which would be better: "a superior member of staff" or "senior member of staff"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

If I want to refer generically to members of staff that are in leading positions/that are the superiors of other staff members, which would be the better choice – *a superior member of staff* or *a senior member of staff*? Or something else entirely?

Examples:

> As a superior/senior member of staff, you have to carry out staff appraisals.

> One of the things you do as a superior/senior member of staff is to organise staff
> meetings

> All superior/senior members of staff need to attend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all three examples you give **senior member of staff** is correct if used in British English.
Maybe in other cultures **superior** is used, but not in the UK.
**Superior** is used when describing the relationship between two members of staff. **senior** is used when describing their position in the company.

> Mr Jones is my **superior** (boss / manager / foreman)
> Mr Jones is a **senior member** of staff.

Answer (score 1):

As a US English speaker, I think *senior* is a much better choice here.

**Superior** has connotations of hierarchy and quality, and sounds like this member of staff is better than others.

*Senior* member of staff is so much more idiomatic that it is really the only natural choice.  [Google Ngrams shows that *senior member* is vastly more common than *superior member*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=senior+member%2Csuperior+member&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csenior%20member%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuperior%20member%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csenior%20member%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuperior%20member%3B%2Cc0), so *superior* also stands out just because of how unusual it is.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I wish it'd be possible to check more than one answer as the accepted answer...